# $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$ for solid angle steradian , working mechanism.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$ for solid angle  steradian , working mechanism. How will it work? For radian is 2D , i want for 3D.

Comment: This question is interesting because it asks for the 3D equivalent of Euler's formula.

Comment: Could you tell more about what you need? As it is the question is very unclear.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Answer (score 0):

Since 1steradian=1rad^2 $ e^{ix^2}=cos (x^2) + i sin (x^2)$. So put $\sqrt \pi$ steradian to get $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: $e^{i\sqrt \pi sr}=-1 $

Comment: radians and steradians are angular measures not numbers. There is no way to compute the exponential of a radian or a steradian.